# Gradle complains about missing "setupMethod" with initial integration test structure

Tags: groovy, gradle, spock, nebula-test

I'm writing my first Gradle plugin.  The default build works fine, including a small number of unit tests.  I'm now trying to set up an integration test infrastructure, using nebula.test.

I created an empty integration test class, along with settings in my build.gradle to configure the "integTest" task and related sourcesets and dependencies.  I used several examples on the net and existing plugins on github to guide me.

Before I show my code, this is the error I get:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: setupMethod for class: org.spockframework.runtime.model.SpecInfo
>   Possible solutions: setupMethods

Here's my "build.gradle" file:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'java-gradle-plugin'
    apply plugin: 'maven'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven { url "http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot" }
        maven { url "http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.release" }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.9"
        compile gradleApi()
        compile "org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-parser-impl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT"
        compile "org.opendaylight.yangtools:binding-java-api-generator:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT"
        compile "org.opendaylight.yangtools:binding-generator-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT"
        compile "org.opendaylight.yangtools:binding-generator-impl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT"
        compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"

        testCompile("org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.3") {
            exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy"
        }
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.7

    group = 'com.att.opnfv.yang'
    version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

    sourceSets {
        integTest {
            groovy.srcDir file("src/integTest/groovy")
            resources.srcDir file("src/integTest/resources")
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        integTestCompile sourceSets.main.output
        integTestCompile configurations.testCompile
        integTestCompile sourceSets.test.output
        integTestRuntime configurations.testRuntime

        testCompile( 'com.netflix.nebula:nebula-test:2.2.0' ) {
            exclude module: 'groovy-all'
        }
    }

    task integTest(type: Test) {
        testClassesDir  = sourceSets.integTest.output.classesDir
        classpath     = sourceSets.integTest.runtimeClasspath
    }

    check.dependsOn -= integTest
```

And here's my simple integration test spec (I added the one "def" after the first try, which made no difference):

```
import nebula.test.IntegrationSpec
class YangPluginIntegSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
    def 'simple'() {
        writeHelloWorld("com.example")
    }
}
```

**Update**:

Here's the complete stacktrace for the error.

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: setupMethod for class: org.spockframework.runtime.model.SpecInfo
>   Possible solutions: setupMethods
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:51)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:63)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
>       at com.energizedwork.spock.extensions.TempDirectoryInterceptor.install(TempDirectoryExtension.groovy:92)
>       at com.energizedwork.spock.extensions.TempDirectoryInterceptor$install.call(Unknown Source)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>       at com.energizedwork.spock.extensions.TempDirectoryExtension.visitFieldAnnotation(TempDirectoryExtension.groovy:21)
>       at com.energizedwork.spock.extensions.TempDirectoryExtension.visitFieldAnnotation(TempDirectoryExtension.groovy)
>       at org.spockframework.runtime.ExtensionRunner.doRunAnnotationDrivenExtensions(ExtensionRunner.java:100)
>       at org.spockframework.runtime.ExtensionRunner.runAnnotationDrivenExtensions(ExtensionRunner.java:65)
>       at org.spockframework.runtime.ExtensionRunner.runAnnotationDrivenExtensions(ExtensionRunner.java:60)
>       at org.spockframework.runtime.ExtensionRunner.runAnnotationDrivenExtensions(ExtensionRunner.java:51)
>       at org.spockframework.runtime.ExtensionRunner.run(ExtensionRunner.java:41)
>       at org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik.runExtensionsIfNecessary(Sputnik.java:88)
>       at org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik.getDescription(Sputnik.java:55)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:83)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:64)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
>       at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
>       at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:106)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
>       at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

I then tried stepping through this code in the debugger.  I was able to hit the breakpoint at AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(), line 227.  It hit this breakpoint several dozen times in my test case.  I also set a breakpoint at GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(), line 63, but for some reason it never hits that breakpoint.

The "callGetProperty()" method looks like this:

```
public Object callGetProperty(Object receiver) throws Throwable {
    return acceptGetProperty(receiver).getProperty(receiver); // 227
}
```

That method looks like this:

```
public final Object getProperty(Object receiver) throws Throwable {
    try {
        return effective.getProperty(receiver); // line 61
    } catch (GroovyRuntimeException gre) {
        throw ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(gre); // line 63
    }
}
```

As line 63 is in a catch clause, I also set a breakpoint on line 61, and that breakpoint is never hit either.

**Update**:

Another interesting point is the TempDirectoryInterceptor.install() method one call up the stacktrace:

```
@Override
void install(SpecInfo spec) {
    spec.setupMethod.addInterceptor this // line 92
    spec.cleanupMethod.addInterceptor this
}
```

There's the "setupMethod", but I don't know what that's supposed to be.  A breakpoint set on this line does not get hit.

Comment: I found the problem. nebula.test brings in spock 0.7, and I was using spock 1.0. I'll write a full answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment, The latest release of nebula.test requires Spock 0.7.  If you also specify Spock 1.0 as a dependency, chaos will ensue.  The fix is to remove the separate reference to Spock 1.0.

Fortunately, nebula.test will likely be upgraded to use Spock 1.0 relatively soon.  The following PR request is pending: https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-test/pull/33 .